# Returning variable in def paragraph

Tags: python-2.7

Why didn't python return the variable in def paragraph? It worked if not in def paragraph.

Here is my code:

```
def find_message(text):
    t=''.join([c for c in text if c.isupper()])
    return t

find_message("How are you? Eh, ok. Low or Lower? Ohhh.")
```

It didn't return anything, but if run the same thing without using def it worked well:

```
s = 'How are you? Eh, ok. Low or Lower? Ohhh.'
t=''.join([c for c in s if c.isupper()])
print t
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: It is returning, you just do nothing with the returned value!

Answer (score 1):

I know this sounds dumb but perhaps this will work?

```
def find_message(text):
   t=''.join([c for c in text if c.isupper()])
   return t

# IMPORTANT! Print returned message
print find_message("How are you? Eh, ok. Low or Lower? Ohhh.")
```

Comment: I think this is right, assuming you're running the above code as a script rather than interactively.